# How can I set the processor affinity of a process on Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, process

How can I set the processor affinity of a process on Linux?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have used taskset for this. If you have taskset installed, something like:

```
taskset -cp 0,2 45678
```

would set the process with id 45678 to have an affinity to cpus 1 and 3.

Comment: I'm getting: `taskset: failed to execute -p: No such file or directory`.

Comment: maybe `taskset` changed it's params since I originally posted this?

Comment: Syntax seems to be `taskset -pc 0,2 45678`

Comment: fixed, thanks. Actually tested on a cmdline. As of now. `-cp` is correct

Comment: Usage in the form `taskset -pc cpulist pid` e. g. `taskset -pc 0,3,7-11 700` is actually included in compiled-in help (tested on taskset from util-linux 2.32.1 and 2.29.2). Both `-cp` and `-pc` work for me.

Answer (score 10):

Inside the process, the call would be `sched_setaffinity()`, or for pthreads stuff, `pthread_setaffinity_np()`

On a related note, if you're worrying about CPU affinity of your program, it may be worthwhile to pay attention to how it's doing memory allocation as well. Larger systems with memory attached to more than one controller (i.e. multiple CPU sockets, each with their own) will have variable latency and bandwidth between different CPU-memory pairs. You'll want to look into NUMA affinity as well, using the `numactl` command or the system calls that it works with. One program I worked on got a 10% performance improvement from this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `schedutils` (Linux scheduler utilities).
I have use it on my Ubuntu Desktop.

SF [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schedutils/)

Answer (score 4):

```
taskset -c 1-3 ./a.out arg1 arg2
```

launches the `a.out` process with given arguments and affinity set to processors 1, 2 or 3 (zero based).

Here is a minimal C test program that can be used to see it in action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490756/how-to-use-sched-getaffinity-and-sched-setaffinity-in-linux-from-c/50117787#50117787