# How can taskset create pid when the program is not running yet?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, cpu, taskset

I want to limit the processing capability to only a single core in my machine, so I found out `taskset` can help to set a single core, say core 0, as the following (Courtesy to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81/269028)):

```
taskset -c 0 -p 45678
```

The problem is that how can I determine the process_id pid here when my program is not running yet? Do we just set an arbitrary process id to be picked up by Linux, in this case `45678`? If it is so, is it possible to do that in a shell script as the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Set the processing unit
taskset -c 0 -p 45678

# run python script
python main.py
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call `taskset` to record the settings to be used for a future process. This mode of calling `taskset` is only for currently-running processes.

To pin a new process to a core, call `taskset` in its direct mode. You call `taskset` and tell it what program to execute.

```
taskset -c 0 python main.py
```

The way it works is:

1. The shell (or other calling program) creates a new process ([`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))) to execute ([`execve`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call))) `taskset -c 0 python main.py`.
2. The process running `taskset` applies the core settings to itself.
3. The process executes (`execve` again) `python main.py` in the same process.

This is the way other per-process settings are made: environment variables when you set them for a single process (e.g. with `env`) rather than for a shell session (e.g. with `export`), CPU niceness with `nice`, redirections (which is typically done through shell syntax rather than with a separate utility), etc.